# what is the relevence of mentioning no of tasks in storm

Tags: apache-storm

I just wanted to know what is the `actual relevance of using tasks in storm with respect to the output or performance` since it does not have to do anything with parallelism, so on choosing more than 1 task for a component `will make any change in output? or what will be the flow than?` Or if i choose no of `tasks > executors` how does that make difference in flow or the output (here i am just taking the basic word count example).
It would be very helpful if anybody could explain me this with or without example.

for example say-
I have a `topology with 3 bolts and 1 spout`, and i have mentioned only `2 workers port`,than that means that all these 4 components(1 spot and 3 bolts will get run on these workers only) now i have mentioned `2 executors for 1st bolt` than it means that there will be 2 thread of that bolt will be running in parallel.Now if i mention the `no of task=3` `how will this make difference whether in output or performance?` 
And if i have mentioned the `field grouping` than the grouping will be there in different executors(plz correct me if m wrong)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you read this article? https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Understanding-the-parallelism-of-a-Storm-topology.html

To pick up your example: If you set `#tasks=3` and specify `2 executors` using `fieldsGrouping` the data will be partitioned into 3 substreams (= #tasks). 2 substreams go to one executor and the third to the second executor. However, using 3 tasks and 2 executors, allows you to increase the number of executors to 3 using `rebalance` command.

As long as you do not want to increase the number of executors during execution, #tasks should be equal to #executors (ie, just don't specify #tasks).

For your example (if you don't want to change the parallelism at runtime), you most likely can an imbalance workload for both executors (one executor processed 33% of the data, the other 66%). However, this is only a problem in this special case and not in general. If you assume you have 4 tasks, each executors processed 2 substreams and no inbalance occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Matthias, I got the point.
I have one more question - Can you plz tell me if i don't mention any field grouping explicitly than what is the default strategy of distribution ?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question... If you connect a bolt to a producer (either spout or bolt), you always need to specify the connection pattern you want to use explicitly. So, there is no default strategy. Please see https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Concepts.html